# Decision Trees (Random Forest and Random Tree) classification on a small data set. Something wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I performed classification on a small data set 65x9 using Decision Trees (Random Forest and Random Tree). I have four classes and 8 Attributes and 65 Instances.

My Application is in assistive robotics. So,Im extracting some parameters from my sensor data that I think are relevant to classify the users run while they are performing some task. I get the movement data from the sensor package deployed on the wheelchair. Im classify certain action like turning 180 degree, and Im giving him a mark (from 1 to 4) So from the sensor package and the software I had extracted parameters like velocity, distance, time, standard deviation of the velocity etc. that are relevant for the classification of the users run. So my data are all numbers.

When I performed Decision Trees Classify I got this Results

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Random forest of 10 trees, each constructed while considering 4 random features.
Out of bag error: 0.5231



Time taken to build model: 0.01 seconds

=== Evaluation on training set ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances          64               98.4615 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         1                1.5385 %
Kappa statistic                          0.9791
Mean absolute error                      0.0715
Root mean squared error                  0.1243
Relative absolute error                 19.4396 %
Root relative squared error             29.0038 %
Total Number of Instances               65     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 1         0          1         1         1          1        c1
                 1         0          1         1         1          1        c2
                 0.952     0          1         0.952     0.976      1        c3
                 1         0.019      0.917     1         0.957      1        c4
Weighted Avg.    0.985     0.003      0.986     0.985     0.985      1    

=== Confusion Matrix ===

  a  b  c  d   <-- classified as
 14  0  0  0 |  a = c1
  0 19  0  0 |  b = c2
  0  0 20  1 |  c = c3
  0  0  0 11 |  d = c4
```

This is too good. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you use 90% of the training set to train it and 10% to test it, what do you see? I assume you're overfitting right now and will see much less impressive results.

Comment: Than the results are sinking rapidly... not impressive at all. So how to balance that?

Comment: @user3035413 use 20% of data to train, 80% to test. If results are bad that means you don't have enough data. Obtain more!

Comment: Yeah, the results are bad also when use 20% data to train and 80 to test